# Json Jackson Object Mapper IO exception Android

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Im trying to give properties to an object from a Json.

I'm using Jackson, and my problem it's an IO exception when trying to map the Json properties to the object.

This is the object:

```
public class TextBox {
    private String label;
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to assing the Json values to the object.

```
public class JacksonObjectMapperExample {
    public TextBox JsonToTextBox () throws IOException {

        String jsonData="{\n" +
                "\t\"TextBox\" :\n" +
                "\t\t[\n" +
                "\t\t\t{\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\"label\": \"Nombre\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"TextBox\"\n" +
                "\t\t\t}\n" +
                "\t\t]\n" +
                "}";
        //create ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //convert json string to object
        TextBox textbox = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, TextBox.class);
        return textbox;
    }

}
```

I've tried with different kinds of Json Formats, and trying to read it from a file.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove your symbols ("\t", "\n", etc) from your JSON.

You also need to add the @JsonProperty("label") (and type) annotation and create an empty constructor in your TextBox class.

Your JSON String should be (then you can format it):

```
"{TextBox:[{label:Nombre, type:TextBox}]}"
```

But I think this JSON is malformed, why an array inside "TextBox"? I think it should be:

```
"{TextBox:{label:Nombre, type:TextBox}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't fixed it, I tried with both strings, I think it has something to do with how I'm doing the exception handling, I added throws IOException to my main method, but I couldn't do that to my onCreate method (Since Android doesn't let you throw exceptions from there), so I surrounded it with a try catch, but still doesnt work.

Comment: Post your logcat error please, instead f throwing an IO Exception I would try to surround the code with the "JSONException", "JsonParseException" and "IOException".

Comment: If one of the Exception is reached return null or do what you want

Comment: here is my logcat, [link to logcat](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dac345a13049bcb6340f)I've tried the exceptions, and they don't appear to exist in my namespace, it only lets me create them

Comment: I think you were half right, it says it's expecting a double quote: "Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): was expecting double-quote to start field name"  so add the double quotes to your JSON field names: "{\"TextBox\":{\"label\":Nombre, \"type\":TextBox}}" maybe it need them to the values, check your logcat output

Comment: you were right !!, now it reads the contents, but it seems to get confused with the title of the object (TextBox), here is what the LogCat says now: link to Logcat

Comment: You have "TextBox" several times, the problem seems to be on the first field, check your JSON and model again, try to add double quote to fields and values, I don't see any problem (more than the field naming, I wouldn't use reserved words)

Comment: I got it, the TextBox object wasnt being recognized, and the JSON had to have the double quotes in the field names and the value

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the field name TextBox, it was searching for it in the textboxTextBox class and wasn't finding it, I deleted it and formatted my JSON like this:

`"{\n" +
"\t\t\t\t\"label\": \"Nombre\",\n" +
"\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"TextBox\"\n" +
"\t\t\t}";`

As dolphinziyo said, all the /n and /t are optional, here is the logcat that gave it away:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "textBox" (class com.example.ealcazar.jacksontest.TextBox), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "label", "type"])